# Error while Fetching data from database

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I have written a code to fetch the data from database, but its ended up with an error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>           Severity: Notice
>           Message: Undefined index: username
>           Filename: views/userinfo.php
>           Line Number: 20
>           Backtrace:
>
> File: D:\wamp\www\anand\codeigniter\application\views\userinfo.php
>       Line: 20
>       Function: _error_handler
>
> File: D:\wamp\www\anand\codeigniter\application\controllers\Main.php
>   Line: 35 Function: view
>
> File: D:\wamp\www\anand\codeigniter\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

My code is

```
?php
   $name=$this->session->username;
   $pass=$this->session->password;
   $q=$this->db->query("select * from signup where username='$name' and password='$pass'");
   $data=$q->result();
   echo $data['username'];
   echo $data['password'];
?>
```

kindly give a suggestion to fetch the data in a correct format..

Comment: use $data->username; and $data->password;

Comment: yes, i tried that too. yet error exist..

Comment: why are you use in `session` ? and can your more explain how you are handing this request

Comment: you should read this. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html understand result(), row(), result_array().

Comment: if you are submitting the form using `POST` then you can get like this `$_POST['username']` ,but this not the best way to do in CI

Comment: Variables from Controller are passed to View. so i'm using session for the variable 'username' and 'password'. @AmanMaurya

Comment: have you loaded the `session` library in you `config/autoload.php` or in your `controller`?.If yes then use this `$this->session->all_userdata()` to see what is going into the session

Comment: **error is rectified by using** `foreach($q->result() as $data){
echo $data->username; 
echo $data->password;
} `  must be used instead of  `$data=$q->result();

      echo $data['username'];
      echo $data['password'];`

Comment: $this->db->query will return an array of matching rows so $data=$q->result(); should be an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is rectified by using

```
`<?php
        foreach ($q->result() as $data)
        {
        echo $data->username; 
        echo $data->password;
        }
  ?>`
```

instead of

```
`<?php
      $data=$q->result();
      echo $data['username'];
      echo $data['password'];
 ?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 print_r($data);
```

to know the result. It will show you the correctly result.

Answer (score 0):

if there is only one row of result use `result_array()`;

```
  $data=$q->result_array();
  echo $data[0]['username'];
  echo $data[0]['password'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `$q->result() to $q->row_array()`. It will only get an array result and you can directly access the key like $data['username']

```
<?php
   $name=$this->session->username;
   $pass=$this->session->password;
   $q=$this->db->query("select * from signup where username='$name' and password='$pass'");
   $data=$q->row_array();
   echo $data['username'];
   echo $data['password'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this

```
$q->result_array();
foreach($q as $data):

echo $data['username'];
echo $data['password'];

endforeach;
```

If you use `$q->result()` then in the `foreach` do like this

```
echo $data->username;
```